# Not getting data in fetch even if the status is 200 in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having below problem with the fetch function:
React code:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.userService.getLoggedInUser()
        .then(user => {
            this.setState({user: user});
            console.log(this.state.user);
    })
}
```

This the course service file code:

```
getLoggedInUser(){
    const USER_API_URL = API_URL + "/api/profile";
    return fetch(USER_API_URL, {
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        method : "POST"
    }).then(response => response.clone()).then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
    });
}
```

I am just trying to get the logged in user from the server. While using postman to do the same, I am getting the output as expected.
Server Code:

```
@PostMapping("/api/loggedInUser")
public Faculty getLoggedInUser(HttpSession session){
    return (Faculty)session.getAttribute("currentUser");
}
```

Class in the server is defined as:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000", allowCredentials ="true")
public class UserService {
```

In postman, I am getting the below output:

```
{
"id": 100,
"username": "bird",
"password": "bird",
"firstName": "Alice",
"lastName": "Kathie"
}
```

But in the react app, I am getting in the console as:

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:8080/api/profile", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
```

But there is no data body to return or parse. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have tried changing the then method in the fetch to various types, like response.clone().json() etc, but, in most cases, I am getting the output as "promise rejected, unexpected end of json input".
How can I solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: You might want to check this solution and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43547095/3550662

Comment: I checked the solution, but I couldn't find anything in the network type related to headers. Also, I have only developed the api, how to add those lines mentioned in the solution in the code in java backend server?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the error is in how you are handling your response:

```
 }).then(response => response.clone()).then(data => {
```

The data in your second .then() isn't returning the fetch response, it is returning the details of the fetch itself. In `.then(response =>` you probably want to do:

```
.then(response => {
   return response.json()
}
```

It isn't clear what you are trying to do with response.clone(), as this typically creates a clone of the response for use with caching or something -- what are you trying to do with the clone?

If you're using it in a cache function maybe you could:

```
.then(response => {
   someCacheFunction(response.clone())
   return response.json()
}
```

or if you are setting it to a pre-defined variable for some use:

```
var responseClone;
... // code omitted
.then(response => {
   responseClone = response.clone()
   return response.json()
}
```

Comment: If i dont do clone, I am getting the following error: "Promise {<rejected>: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" and "Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream is locked"

Comment: can you please help

Comment: How about ` .then(response => { return response.json() } ).then( myJson => { return JSON.stringify(myJson) } )` Also, can you share what you get if you console.log response, as in response => { console.log(response) } ?

Comment: I getting the following logs "esponsebody: (...)bodyUsed: trueheaders: Headers {}ok: trueredirected: falsestatus: 200statusText: ""type: "cors"url: "http://localhost:8080/api/profile"__proto__: Response
webpack-internal:///./src/services/UserService.js:33 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/services/UserService.js:28)
webpack-internal:///./src/components/WhiteBoard.js:104 undefined
webpack-internal:///./src/components/WhiteBoard.js:110 undefined"

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. Main problem was with the cookies. While fetching, we need to make sure following is set:

```
 getLoggedInUser = () => {
    const USER_API_URL = API_URL + "/api/profile";
    return fetch(USER_API_URL, {
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        method : "POST",
        'credentials': 'include'
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json()
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
    });
}
```

"credentials":"include" is necessary so that the browser is accepting cookies and the same cookie is used to retrieve the data from the server.

Answer (score -1):

I've found that **fetch** is unreliable.  Try **axios** instead. See https://axios-http.com/docs/intro for info, or run `npm i axios` and add it to your project with `import axios from 'axios'`, then call `axios.get(YOUR_URL)`.
Probably too old a thread by now, but maybe this will help a little.