# re-render component after post request api react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After a post request, the data gets inside the database but it is not re rendering the component. I need to manually press the F5 button and the new data will be displayed. It seems like the `then` is not executing.

```
class AddForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            id: null,
            title: "",
            price: 0,
            pages: 0,
        };
    }

    postData() {
        const { title, price, pages } = this.state
        const curTitle = title
        const curPrice = price
        const curPages = pages
        fetch("api/books", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                Title: title,
                Price: price,
                NumberOfPages: pages
            })
        }).then(res => res.json()).then(() => this.setState({ title: curTitle, price: curPrice, pages: curPages }))
    }
}
```

Edit:
When I do the following:

```
.then(response => response.json()).then(res => console.log(res))
```

I get `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

Comment: When you are calling postData function?

Comment: What happens if you add `console.log()` instead of `this.setState()` part in `then()`?

Comment: @HadiRanjbar, when I'm pressing ```handleSubmit``` in my form.

Comment: @norbitrial, when I do: ```.then(response => console.log(response))```, I get ```Unexpected end of JSON input```

Comment: Check this post, it may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362431/uncaught-in-promise-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-json-input

Answer (score 1):

Well from your question it looks like that you are able to make the state update on submitting, the only problem is regarding displaying the data, for that  I may suggest you to put another component for displaying the data. It had worked for me in the past. Just let me know whether it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

**res => res.json()**: this gives a JSON response, bind this JSON response values to the state in the setState.

Hoping your response will be like below,

```
response.data = {
   curTitle: 'some title',
   curPrice: 'some price',
   curPages: 'some pages'
}
```

Change your fetch call second then function like below,

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.state = {
      id: null,
      title: "",
      price: 0,
      pages: 0,
   };
   this.postData = this.postData.bind(this); // Add this line, cannot read property error will be gone.
}

fetch("api/books", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        Title: title,
        Price: price,
        NumberOfPages: pages
    })
}).then(res => res.json()).then((responseJson) => {
  console.log(responseJson); // what is the output of this?
  this.setState({
    title: responseJson.data.curTitle,
    price: responseJson.data.curPrice,
    pages: responseJson.data.curPages
  })
})
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but it's not displaying the new data.

Comment: What is the output of console.log(response)?

Comment: On trying my solution, is there any error you are getting?

Comment: ```Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at``` when I console.log(response)

Comment: Change the second then callback like above and tell me what the console prints their?

Comment: When I do ```.then(res => console.log(res)```, I get my response with the status etc.. When I do ```then(res => res.json()).then((responseJson => console.log(responseJson))``` I get the error that I mentioned above.

Comment: Please exactly do this and tell me: 
.then((responseJson) => {
  console.log(responseJson);
  this.setState({
    title: responseJson.data.curTitle,
    price: responseJson.data.curPrice,
    pages: responseJson.data.curPages
  })
})

Comment: When I exactly type like what you mentioned I get: ```index.js:30 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined```.

Comment: Got it. we need to bind this to postData method to solve the above mentioned error.
Added a line in constructor. Please add that and check

Comment: I added the bind in the constructor, but it is still the same error.

Answer (score -1):

You should create new function which get from back end. Then call this function after post respons

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).